# How to fix page scroll lag in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I have been working on a new static website, it's a very simple build but has a few subtle CSS animations, triggered by `isInViewport` js function.

I have noticed that Chrome renders the page with a small amount of lag on scroll, it's very jarring. Yet in Safari, Firefox it's absolutely fine.

Here is my `js` for triggering when an element is in viewport.

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
  var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
  var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

  var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height() - 100;

  return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

$(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('section').each(function() {
      if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
        $(this).addClass('reveal');
      }
      else {
      }
    });
   }, 300);
});
```

Is there anything out of the ordinary I shouldn't be doing?

And here is the `CSS` relevant to the animation.

```
.image-reveal {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-reveal-cover {
    background: #fcfcfc;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
    transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);

    transition: transform cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.75s;
    -webkit-transition: transform cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.75s;
}

.image-reveal img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);

  transition: all cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.5s;
}

section.reveal .image-reveal-cover {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

section.reveal .image-reveal img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/FearTheWild/pen/OreRed) showing an example of the scroll jitteriness in Chrome.

Am I triggering my animations incorrectly? I thought using transform for the base of CSS movement to be relatively lag free?

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you.

---

Also I am using `Chrome 71.0.3578.98` on `Mac OS Mojave`

Comment: The performance is purely down to the JS implementation of the browser. The only thing you can really do with your logic is to stop re-creating the same jQuery object multiple times. If that's still not performant enough, use plain JS instead of jQuery. If that still doesn't work, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Also note that your Codepen is smooth for me in Chrome, but it would depend on the power of the machine running the browser - that's also true of every browser, though.

Comment: I'm running 4 GHz Intel Core i7 16GB RAM iMac. The Codepen is relatively smooth, but do you not see a very slight choppiness? It's very subtle, but frustrating in comparison to Safari.

Comment: That's odd, I'm using a i5 7600 @ 3.5Ghz on Windows 10 and it's smooth as butter. I'd suggest changing the OS ;)

Comment: Haha, well its reassuring that it may be out of my hands at least. Is using on resize potentially a problem?

Comment: @HeyImArt you can try to add `requestAnimationFrame` or `throttle` your event listeners for do only once, probably that's why you have this issue

Comment: @HeyImArt if you add `console.log('scroll!')` inside you `isInViewport` you will see that your events doesn't fire after your function do something, that's why you probably have some issues

Comment: @20yco hmm okay, would you be kind enough to explain `requestAnimationFrame` please?

Comment: @20yco sounds like you're doing something wrong if you're not seeing the `console.log()`, as it works fine. Also note that `requestAnimationFrame()` is not relevant to anything the OP is doing.

Comment: @HeyImArt `Is using on resize potentially a problem?` It's not a problem as such, but there's a lot of performance pitfalls when you use it. The event is fired for every single pixel the UI is scrolled by, therefore you can potentially trigger *a lot* of events very quickly, and if those events are handled by logic which is relatively slow you get the jumpiness as the renderer struggles to keep up.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as you can see i sad that console.log() will print `scroll!` on every scroll after function call, i mean that scroll **doesn't fires** after function call and continue to work

Comment: It clearly does as the horse animation (and the console.log, if you add one) is shown. I have no idea what point you're attempting to make.,

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i mean that `isInViewport` continues to work after element appears, and that's not good, OP need to prevent function calls after element appears, that's all

Comment: Right, ok. However that's not addressing the actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this example i have too much concerns;

- Get rid of Jquery it is slow and you can do everything with JS (http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)
- Why timeout? You don't need it. If you are going to use it kill other timeouts so it will not be duplicated.
- Use ES6(Easy to understand, read and code) Also you can compile to lower versions. It keeps you updated in your career path.
- Don't run selectors for each scroll. Use selector before fire scroll.

Here the example:

```js
class ScrollControl {
  constructor() {
    this.sectionDOMList = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    this.initListeners();
  }

  initListeners() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
      this.animateSections();
    });
  }

  animateSections() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.sectionDOMList.length; i++) {
      if (this.isInViewport(this.sectionDOMList[i])) {
       if(!this.sectionDOMList[i].isReveal){
          this.sectionDOMList[i].isReveal = true;
          this.sectionDOMList[i].classList.add('reveal');
        }
      }
    }
  }

  isInViewport(element) {
    const elementCenter = (element.getBoundingClientRect().top + element.getBoundingClientRect().bottom)/2;
    const viewportTop = window.scrollY;
    const viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.innerHeight;
    return elementCenter < viewportBottom;
  }
}

(function() {
  new ScrollControl();
})();
```

```css
/* Reset */

html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

/* Base */

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  font-family: 'Larsseit', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1640px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-right: 80px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  .container {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}

.vc {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.vc-ele {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

section {
  padding: 400px 0;
}

section.full-vh {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col-half {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-half {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.row.align-center {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* Typography */

h1 {
  font-size: 52px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 26px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Larsseit', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #3b3b3b;
}

/* Image reveal */

.image-reveal {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-reveal-cover {
  background: #fcfcfc;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.75s;
  -webkit-transition: transform cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.75s;
}

.image-reveal img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1.4);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 1.5s;
}

section.reveal .image-reveal-cover {
  transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}

section.reveal .image-reveal img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="container">

    <section class="full-vh">
      <div class="vc">
        <div class="vc-ele">
          <h1>Scroll down</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="row align-center">

        <div class="col-half">
          <div class="image-reveal">
            <div class="image-reveal-cover"></div>
            <img src="https://fearthewild.com/clients/playground/horse.jpg" alt="Horse" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-half">
          <h2>This is my horse.</h2>
          <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem
            quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
          <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
            ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you advice to not use jQuery because it is slow you should also advice to not use event listeners on the scroll event because this is also slow. Rather use Intersection Observer if you need to track visibility of an element.

Comment: I would love to see the benchmark test for 'one scroll listener, getBoundingClientRect(); for 1000 elements' vs '1000 elements with Intersection Observers' :) @cloned

Comment: It's still only one IO with thousand elements inside, just like with one scroll event listener. So in theory it should still perform better. If any one of us is bored we should try to create a jsfiddle or something to test this out in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Don't listen to scroll (or resize) events and then calculate if elements are in viewport, rather use [Intersection Observer (IO)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) for this.

IO observers one (or multiple) elements and reacts if they intersect either with each other or with the viewport.

First, you have to specify your options for your IO:

```
let options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

In your case you need to test for intersecting with window, so no `root` value needs to specified for options. We also specify that a function named callback is getting executed whenever the IO is getting triggered.

Next step is to define the elements that should be observed, in your case these would be section elements:

```
let targets = document.querySelectorAll('section');
targets.forEach(target => {
  observer.observe(target);
});
```

Now everything is set up, all that's left to do is to define what should actually happen in the callback function:

```
let callback = (entries, observer) => { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
    // target element
    // I think you are be interested in entry.isIntersecting check. 
  });
};
```

Also [check this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API#Result) on how to change background color based on how much the box is visible in the viewport.

You can also use this [polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver) to support older browsers.

Comment: Please note that IO is NOT supported in IE, if you care

Comment: That's why I linked to the polyifll in my last sentence, with this you can use IO in IE. It recreates IO by using event listeners to scroll event. While this is not as performant as IO but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

The delay in Chrome scrolling effects behaviour can be caused by CSS. Try removing the scroll-behavior rule if you have one on your html or body element.

Remove this line:
`scroll-behavior: smooth`